# Cannot read property 'columnName' of undefined in sails Js Mongo DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, sails-mongo

I am using sails JS with Mongo DB.
My model is:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    title:{type:"string",required:true},
    content:{type:"string",required:true},
    date:{type:"string",required:true},
    filename:{type:"string",required:true},
  },
};
```

My Controller is:

```
fetchposts:function(req,res){
        console.log("in fetch posts")
        mysort={$id:-1}
  
       Cyberblog.find().sort(mysort).limit(5).exec(function(err, result) {
            if (err || !result) {
                 message="no records fetched";
                 console.log(message);
                 res.redirect('/newpost');
                 }
             else{
                console.log(result)
             }
```

I am facing an error saying that

"Warning: The `sort` clause in the provided criteria is specified as a dictionary (plain JS object),
meaning that it is presumably using Mongo-Esque semantics (something like `{ fullName: -1, rank: 1 }`).
But as of Sails v1/Waterline 0.13, this is no longer the recommended usage.  Instead, please use either
a string like `'fullName DESC'`, or an array-like `[ { fullName: 'DESC' } ]`.
(Since I get what you mean, tolerating & remapping this usage for now...)

and I am unable to fetch any records. It is showing no records fetched.

So I have one warning on Sort and no records coming from DB. Please help me resolve the issue.

Comment: I came here looking for information related to the error message quoted in the title, but the question doesn't seem to have anything to do with the error in the title. Could you change the title to avoid misleading future searchers? Or change the question so the relationship to the title is clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort clause allow send string:

```
var users = await User.find({ name: 'Jake'})
.sort('age ASC');

return res.json(users);
```

Or an array:

```
var users = await User.find({ name: 'Finn'})
.sort([
  { age: 'ASC' },
  { createdAt: 'ASC' },
]);

return res.json(users);
```

Check this out in the documentation:

https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/queries/sort

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for the answer.. But I have no criteria while retrieving the data like "name:finn".. I just want the latest five records.. isn't that possible in sails-mongo?

Comment: You can filter the last items with await Model.find().sort(’createdAt DESC’).limit(5)